# Losing internet connection intermittently

Tags: windows-7, router, internet-connection, modem

Recently I've been experiencing my internet connection being lost. The yellow triangle signals no internet connection and then picks it up again after a couple of seconds.
It could be that it's been doing this for some time. I first noticed it after I started playing an MMORPG, and it annoys the hell out of me every time it happens. The intervals range from 5-45 minutes. When streaming/downloading it occurs more frequently.
Sometimes it doesn't even pick up the connection and just refuses to cooperate.

I've got a web server running, but it shouldn't affect my connection. At least it didn't on Windows XP.

I've got a static IP address. I've tried letting it dynamically get the IP address but that doesn't make any difference.

At one point, I thought it could be that the modem/router got overheated or something. 
So, I turned it off for a day to see if it would help. It didn't.

I removed the router out of the equation and put the cable directly into the modem. 
That did seem to work, but my web server stopped working.

I'm at wits end here...

---

Relevant specs:

```
           OS: Windows 7 Professional
        Modem: Netgear DM111P
       Router: Netgear WGR614 v7, software up to date
Networks card: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, all drivers up to date
          ISP: Bredbandsbolaget (Sweden)
```

Analysis from the university of Berkeley's website Networks analyzer reported the following problems:

```
Direct probing of DNS resolvers (?) –
    Your system is configured to use 1 DNS resolver(s).
    The resolver at 192.168.1.1 (ns6.bredband.com) could not process the following tested types:

        Medium (~1300B) TXT records
        Large (~3000B) TXT records
        Large (~3000B) TXT records fetched with EDNS0

    It validates DNSSEC. It does not wildcard NXDOMAIN errors. The resolver reports a number of additional properties. Hide them.

        Hostname: ns6.bredband.com
        Version: Telenor DNS
```

Comment: When your connection is out, is the link light still on at both ends? Can you still reach the router? Is this DSL?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes to all three. 1) Yes. 2) Yes, I can still reach the router. 3) Yes, ADSL.

Comment: Is this wired or wireless? Does it happen on both?

Comment: your web server stopped working probably because the IP changed from local to the static ip when you removed the router.

Comment: @ShadowScripter: Then I'll go with missing DSL filter. Perhaps you moved a cordless phone base station, added an alarm system, or something like that. Some device connected to your phone line is missing a filter and that's what's killing your DSL link.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The only device I've got connected to my phone line is my modem. I use a mobile phone instead of a home phone.

Comment: @Logman Yeah that's exactly what happened.